# Windows Service using NServicebus SqlTransport and Persistence throws timeout exception

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-services, timeout, nservicebus

We're using NServiceBus with SqlServerTransport and NHibernatePersistence in a Windows Service (using TopShelf and Autofac as IOC).

It all runs smooth for a couple of hours, but after a while the service starts throwing SQL Timeout exceptions. 
There are no other problems with other applications that connect to the same database and NServicebus is upgraded to the latest version (5.2.15).

First thing that comes to my mind is that the Max SQL server connection pool (default 100) has been reached, but I'm not sure.

NServicebus is configured as follows:

```
var _busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();

_busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
_busConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
_busConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>()
                 .ConnectionString(_Connectionstring)
                 .DisableSchemaUpdate();

_busConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(scope));

_busConfiguration.Transactions()
                 .Enable()
                 .DisableDistributedTransactions();

_busConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>()
                 .DefaultSchema("dbo")
                 .ConnectionString(_Connectionstring);
```

This is the stack trace

```
WARN  2016-09-07 19:07:55,528 16868322ms SqlServerPollingDequeueStrategy          Warn               - An exception occurred when connecting to the configured SQLServer instance 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
   at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.NativeTransactionReceiveStrategy.TryReceiveFrom(TableBasedQueue queue)
   at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.AdaptivePollingReceiver.Try(Boolean& success)
   at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.AdaptiveExecutor`1.ReceiveLoop(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
ClientConnectionId:513b75a0-db8a-43ef-9964-acac90933f58
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

INFO  2016-09-07 19:07:55,528 16868322ms RepeatedFailuresOverTimeCircuitBreaker   InfoFormat         - The circuit breaker for SqlTransportConnectivity is now in the armed state 
WARN  2016-09-07 19:07:55,793 16868587ms SqlServerPollingDequeueStrategy          Warn               - An exception occurred when connecting to the configured SQLServer instance 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
```

Anyone an idea of what I can try ?

Comment: Have you tried bigger connection pools? connection string above is not provided so I can't tell...that usually *is* an issue when sharing the database with other apps and processes...As a matter of fact, I have updated the documentation about that just today! See here about connection pools. http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sqlserver/connection-settings

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But will bigger connection pools not simply postpone the endpoint crash? To be clear, if we restart our service everything works fine again for a couple of hours. But once it crashes, it never recovers...

Comment: Had a chat with the other guys about this...they confirmed my understanding which is, if the database is shared with some other code, e.g. business logic you might have in your handlers, see if you can find something there. In the version of Sql Transport you are using, maximum number of concurrent message receives will never exceed the number of MaximumConcurrencyLevel set for that endpoint (with the default value of 1) so even with the default pool size you should not run out of connections.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL infrastructure is up to snuff? We had a problem with symptoms similar to that before on a project and the reason was because the Availability Groups in SQL Server weren't configured correctly. Have you checked SQL logs?

Comment: I'm investigating that with dba's now. Because, since the problem only occurs at night (when backups etc are run), that might just be a valid assumption.